# EJB container and 3 layers architecture

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, layer

I am new to Java EE. I have read some about web containers and ejb containers, but I do not understand if both logical layer and data persistence layer run in the ejb container or just the logical layer runs there. Could someone explain it to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EJB container manages different EJB components. EJB components are "logical" components like session beans, persistence units, servlets, etc. So all of them managed by EJB container.

Answer (score 0):

**EE container** or application container: Manages the execution of EJB, JMS, JTA run on the Java EE server. It also takes care fot transactions, security, and data sources (JDBC resources).
e.g. JBoss, Glassfish.

**Web container** :  Manages the execution of web pages, servlets, and some EJB components for Java EE applications. Web components and their container run on the Web server such as Jetty, tomcat.